# Passover- Abraham's sacrifice tradition?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question on the main site, but feel it may have been already answered and I am not familiar enough to navigate the tags of your site to find an answer.

Are there any Jewish traditions that hold that the Jewish Passover of Exodus and the Abraham's sacrifice of his son Isaac were held on the 14 day of Nisan?

If this has already been answered could someone point out where to find it.

If not could I post it on the main site?

Comment: Inspired by [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/65987/had-the-catholic-church-a-tradition-of-commemorating-abrahams-sacrifice/65989#65989)?

Comment: Perhaps coincidentally, [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94812/date-of-the-akeida) was just asked. Although it does not ask specifically whether it occurred on Passover, it asks what date it occurred which would include an answer that it occurred on Passover.

Comment: followup: was asked as https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94810/are-there-any-jewish-or-hebrew-traditions-that-hold-that-the-passover-and-the-bi

Answer (score 5):

In general, I think you can always post a question on the main site (assuming it is on-topic, which your example is). It is always better to do a bit of research to see if it has been asked before, but even if you don't or can't it is not the end of the world. If someone later finds that the question has already been asked, they can simply then close yours as a duplicate.

In this particular case, I did a quick search and did not find such a question yet on the site. While it's certainly possible that I missed it, and it has in fact been asked (and I did not do anywhere near an exhaustive search), I don't think there should be any problem with you asking it.

Of course, if you do ask it it is always best to include as much detail as possible – including why you think there might be such a tradition.

If you want to look at relevant tags, we have a tag for the [Binding of Isaac](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac), as well as a tag for [Passover](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passover).

Comment: Thanks Alex for your response. I will wait to see if I or someone else can find something on main, before asking the question.